# How can I automate a sequence of actions involving Eclipse Ant builds, Run configuration and a batch file?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, automation

During a normal day I run the following sequence lots of times, would love to automate it to be able to run it in single click/keyboard key combination .

1. Ant build X
2. Ant build Y
3. Starting a batch file (which starts up Jboss if it matters )
4. Waiting for a specific line to show up in the command line output.
5. Starting a specific Debug configuration in Eclipse
6. Starting a specific Run configuration in Eclipse

Batch file already runs with keyboard shortcut, I think I can automate the next one as well- but how can I tie them to the Eclipse parts ?

Thanks !

(I'm using Windows 7, Eclipse Juno)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible by default (a custom plugin might help you though).

1-4 can be done by creating an External Run Configuration that executes a batch file which encapsulates these tasks.